# Clip out overlapping vector contour data to merge two datasets of differing quality using ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro

I have two data sets, one is LiDAR derived contours (blue in pic), the other is less accurate contours (red in pic).  The two overlap but I would like one dataset where the more accurate is used where available and the less accurate remaining where I do not have LiDAR coverage.

I thought about creating a polygon outline of all my LiDAR coverage and using that clip out a hole in the less accurate contours so I can then paste-in the more accurate LiDAR data, but I don't know how to generate that outline of the data's extent, and not sure if this is the best approach.  Seeking advice if this approach would work and how to go about it.

[image: Blue is LiDAR and red is less accurate, there is more coverage of the red, but i would like to replace the red with the blue data where available]

Comment: Both vector datasets could use a low-pass filter for smoothing before contour creation, but I'd feather the boundary in raster, then smooth, then contour.

Comment: I don't have the original raster the vectors were created from, just the vector product.  Intended end result is not a DEM raster, but a vector dataset merging the two sets of contour lines but without doubling up in the areas where I have LiDAR derived vectors.

Comment: Intersect 2 sets - to points. Convert into single parts. Split non=liidar at points. Compute near table between splits and points. Frequency table of that gives you lines, that touch 2 points. They are to be removed.

Comment: Or compute dangling points of splits, they mark segments to be removed